# Suppose $E(X|Y, Z=1) = E(X|Y, Z=0)$, is $E(X|Z=1) = E(X|Z=0)?$

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X, Y, Z$ are random variables. Assume $E(X|Y, Z=1) = E(X|Y, Z=0)$ holds. Is it true that $E(X|Z=1) = E(X|Z=0)?$

Here's my attempt:
\begin{align*}
E(X|Z=1) &= E(E(X|Y, Z=1)|Z=1)\\
&= E(E(X|Y, Z=0)|Z=1)\\
&\neq E(E(X|Y, Z=0)|Z=0)
\end{align*}

Therefore, $E(X|Z=1) \neq E(X|Z=0)$. Is the above correct?

Comment: What does $E(X|Y,Z=1)$ indicate?

Comment: A case when it holds is when Y is exogeneous to X and Z. If not, then in general the result does not follow.

Comment: Why the second equation should not be a consequence of the first one, just taking expectations of both members ?

Comment: @Math-fun That makes sense. I agree with your comment. However, Thomas' comment/answer contradicts this, so I'm not sure which one is correct.

Comment: Your notation $E(X|Z=1) = E(E(X|Y, Z=1)|Z=1)$ with two conditions makes no sense.

Comment: @Adrian feel free to check my answer. I also left a comment under Thomas's answer, to explain where I think his error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $X = Y$ be a standard Gaussian, and let $Z$ be a noisy observation of whether $Y > 0$. (i.e. say $Z = 1_{Y > 0} + Z'$ where $Z' \sim Bernoulli(1/3)$, and addition is to be thought of XORing).

Then, the conditional expectations you gave are equal (they are both $Y$), but certainly, the claim made in the question is false.

Answer (score 0):

I think the equality may hold. Please correct me if you find errors.

I would claim that :

$$ E[E[X|Y,Z=a]]=E[X|Z=a] \ [1]$$

for a fixed value $a$.

Intuitively, this is the tower property where instad of the original measure we have the measure conditioned on the event $Z=a$.  We can check it in a more explicit way. First write the conditional expectation as a function of the density:

$E[X|Y,Z=a]=\int dx x p(x|Y,Z=a)$

and than take expectation values:

$E[E[X|Y,Z=a]]=\int dy p(y|z=a)\int dx x p(x|y,z=a)$

Now using that:

$\int p(x|y,z=a)p(y|z=a)dy=p(x|z=a)$

we have:

$E[E[X|Y,Z=a]]=\int dx x p(x|z=a)=E[X|Z=a]$

, therefore showing [1], if no mistakes are there. Once we have [1], the fact that:

$$ E[X|Z=1]=E[X|Z=0]$$

follows by taking expectation values of the original condition.

Comment: The post received a downside without comments. Could the author please clarify if the reasonings are problematic?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but the step that breaks is when you take "expectations of both sides". The problem with this is that for one side, you would want to take expectations w.r.t. $Y \mid Z = 0$ and the other one w.r.t. $Y \mid Z = 1$. It is subtle, and I spent a fair bit coming up with my example.

Comment: @E-A That makes sense thanks a lot :) ... I will leave anyway my post since, as far as I understand, identity 1 is true, even if we cannot use it to deduce the claim. Is it like that?

Comment: Yup, indeed, as you say, identity you showed follows from tower rule, (and you don't need densities), but it doesn't prove the claim in the question (and it can't, as it is in general false).

Comment: I am also not a downvoter :-) I though would not agree with [1] being fine. law of iterated expectations for conditional expecations is $E(Y|\Omega_1) = E(E (Y|\Omega_1,\Omega_2) |\Omega_1)$, where the $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ have a measure different from $0$.

Comment: @Math-fun Thanks a lot. If we apply your equation with \Omega_1 the sigma algebra generated by Y and \Omega_2 the sigma algebra generated by the event Z=a, we would obtain E[E[X|Y,Z=a]|Z=a]=E[X|Z=a], which is actually closer to what I verified in the case of existing densities ( when I take the expectation over y, I condition over p(y|z=a) ). Would this form be the correct one in your opinion ?

Comment: Actually, this form of the equation had already been used by the OP

Comment: I believe that what the OP is doing is fine saying that the claim in incorrect. I see your treatments regarding how conditional expectations work, but unfortuenately you have started with "leaving one conditioning out". I did not check the derivations ... :-)

Comment: @Math-fun Maybe there is a misunderstanding. I am not trying to claim that the OP is wrong. I agree with you that the claim is incorrect, I am just trying to fix my post for learning purposes ;)

Comment: I see: I think it would be best to open a question (my suggestion). This will be better to attract the attention of the community :-)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, probably I will cancel my post and open a new question when I have a bit of time :) . In the meanwhile, I thank you for the corrections